# How do you view deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, 10k-tools

10k rep members are allowed to see deleted questions, is there a way to find questions that were deleted or to see a list of them somewhere?

Comment: Here is another list: http://www.stackprinter.com/deleted

Comment: @Matt funny how that is now a deleted question

Comment: why i can not see mine?

Comment: For recently deleted questions: http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/<your_id> (see the ID when you are on your stackoverflow profile).

Answer (score 26):

If you have 10k rep, you can also see a list of recently deleted questions in the Moderation Tools.

[image: Deleted Questions]

Comment: Where? I don't see it.

Comment: @msh210, see update. Click on the "Tools" and make sure you're on the Delete tab.

Comment: I don't see a "Tools" link. Is it supposed to be atop the page? I'm a diamond mod, and see only "mod" and "review" there -- and neither of those has a "Delete" tab. Is this something 10k users can see and diamond mods can't? (That'd be very strange.)

Comment: Oh! Found it: it's at `/tools` (and has a "Delete" tab, as you said). Oddly, though, there doesn't seem to be a link to that page from anywhere (for me).

Comment: The Tools link is replace by the Review link and vice-versa, depending on how you enter the pages.

Comment: What if it's not recent?

Comment: is there such an option in SO too?

Comment: Can we see specific user deleted questions?

Answer (score 20):

Use `deleted:1` in your search to see your own deleted posts, assuming you have over 10k rep.

From the [10k rep privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> Viewing deleted posts
>
> You now have privileged access to posts that have been removed, either
>   by their authors, by users with access to moderator tools, by
>   moderators, or by the system.
>
> Use this privilege wisely:
>
> - Make sure what is being deleted should have been deleted, and bring unnecessary or harmful deletions to the attention of the community
>     and/or moderator team.
> - Watch for signs of abuse being obscured by deletion.
> - Don't abuse this privilege to stir up trouble when someone has wisely decided to remove a problematic post.
>
> You also have a new search operator available to find your own deleted
>   posts: deleted:1.

Comment: That only returns *your own* deleted posts.

Comment: @Cai true, still a valid answer with good tip.

Comment: @Sha sure, wasn't implying otherwise, just adding important information :)

Comment: If you are a moderator, this allows you to see all deleted posts.

Comment: That's odd you need ≥10k reputation to view one's own deleted questions.

Answer (score 16):

For very recently deleted questions where you know the exact title you may be able to see the google cached version of the page.  Google the exact title, click on the down arrow next to the green link, click "Cached".

Comment: Whoa, interesting secret... seems it may have some "shady" uses.

Answer (score 8):

You need to have the direct link to the question.  They also show up if you have previously starred them as a favorite question.

Comment: Do direct links always work though? Sometimes when my questions get deleted, I try to view the comments to them but I can't because the thread's all gone... Everything at http://www.stackprinter.com/deleted is unviewable.

Comment: A direct link will take you to a "question deleted" page.

Comment: @Gnemlock If you have 10K+ rep you can still see the question via direct link.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not possible (without [access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)), but if these are your own questions and you were down-voted for these questions, go to 'reputation' from your profile and select 'show removed posts', they'll appear, but not linked. Based on the removed title, you may try to find the direct link either in your web-browser history, Google Cache or [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/).

Answer (score 5):

[Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) has PostsWithDeleted table which contains *some* information on deleted questions. (You can see details here: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677).)

This means that from SEDE you can get list of links to deleted questions, together with some information (such as tags, score, number of answers, dates of creation and deletion of the post, etc.) However, you don't see the title or the user who posted the question/answer - for that you have to click on the link. Of course, you'll see the question only if it is viewable for you - i.e., you have 10k+ on the given site or you are the poster (or author of an answer to the deleted question).

You can restrict the list by some specific criteria (score, specific tag, number of answers, etc.) Here are some examples of such queries (do not forget to switch to the site you are interested in):

- [Recently deleted questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/845043/recently-deleted-questions?number=100)
- [Recently deleted answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/845045/recently-deleted-answers?number=100)
- [Questions deleted between two dates](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/845247/questions-deleted-between-two-dates)
- [Answers deleted between two dates](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/845250/answers-deleted-between-two-dates)
- [Deleted questions between two dates in a specific tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/845253/deleted-questions-between-two-dates-in-a-specific-tag?TagName=deleted-questions&Date1=2018-01-01&Date2=2019-01-01)
- [Deleted answers posted between two dates - in a specific tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/968724/deleted-answer-posted-between-two-dates-in-a-specific-tag?tagname=deleted-questions)
- [Deleted questions with high score](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/845039/deleted-questions-with-high-score-including-link?number=100)
- [Deleted answers with high score](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/845272/deleted-answers-with-high-score?number=100)
- [Deleted questions with many answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/845040/deleted-questions-with-many-answers-including-link?number=100)
- [Deleted questions with high score in a specific tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/845254/deleted-questions-with-high-score-in-a-specific-tag?number=100&Tagname=deleted-questions)
- [Deleted questions with many answers in a specific tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/845255/deleted-questions-with-many-answers-in-a-specific-tag?number=100&Tagname=deleted-questions)

Comment: There is more detailed information about the PostsWithDeleted table specifically here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462/can-some-metadata-about-deleted-posts-be-included-in-data-se/266431#266431

Comment: There are several similar queries in this post on [math.meta,se]: [Are there some tools to follow deletions on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28315#28316) (I have added a few more to these ones.)

Answer (score 2):

Go to your **Inbox** and search for messages related to the question you are looking for. 
This solution works whatever reputation you have, and even if the question was deleted over 60 days ago.