# SEDE query for posts flagged as NAA

Tags: support, review, flags, data-explorer

I am trying to figure out where in the [database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/325443) is stored the information about the kind of flag that has eventually been raised on a given answer.

It seems spam/offensive flags should generate some kind of entry in the `Votes` table with `VoteTypeId` 12 or 4. But it actually doesn't, for the posts I checked (as an example, see [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/1084160), this was a [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/440571/107479) I flagged as spam myself - you need 10k on EE.SE to see it, though - you can see the downvotes, the deletion, the fact it was sent in moderator review queue, but no explicit trace of a spam flag).

Regarding the NAA flags, I don't see anything in the schema that could directly relate to this.

**But why do I need this?**

Because there has been this question: [Someone has been upvoting nonsense non-answers](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7003/someone-has-been-upvoting-nonsense-non-answers) on meta EE.SE. And I recently realized that we could actually get some information about [deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331577/325443) on SEDE. So I thought: "Hey, imma just make a query to get the posts that have upvotes while having been flagged as NAA, to check if there has been an increase of these cases recently!"

But it seems I can't, can I? The only thing I can do is checking if the post has been in the moderator review queue (`VoteTypeId = 15`), which should have been the case for all flagged posts, whetever the kind of flag raised.

Comment: I doubt if the votes table still receives that info. I can only imagine it has a record while there still is a pending spam flag on that post. AFAIK there is no flag information in the public SEDE. At best you could look at ReviewTasks as an NAA flag will probably end-up for review (unless a mod got to it earlier) and then that only works for non-deleted posts.

Answer (score 1):

You're out of luck, I guess.

Flags aren't stored in SEDE (the `PendingFlags` table stores something else, and the votes *might* be the automatic downvotes caused by spam/rude/abusive flags). NAA and VLQ flags usually make the post end up in review queues, of which some data *is* stored in SEDE, review tasks for deleted posts are not included in SEDE.

With a little luck, your EE.Meta post attracts a ♦ moderator who is willing to dig into these posts. They might observe a pattern in IP addresses or email addresses and confirm that there's a voting ring at work, but such investigations can be long and unfruitful.